# removing tags from a car

Tags: united-states, property, insurance

My son passed away and I had his car bought down from Baltimore to Fla. near West Palm Beach.

His estate is in probate and it will take 6 or months or more for it to be settled. I stopped insurance payments on it and they said I had to send the tags back.

I live in an unincorporated rural area, own my home and property, and its paid for.

Will they tow my car if it is sitting in my yard with no tags?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the "they" who told you this is the insurance agent. They (the state) will not tow the car if it is on private property, especially since this is a Maryland matter and the car is in Florida. [Maryland law](http://www.mva.maryland.gov/about-mva/info/27300/27300-04T.htm) requires one to return license plates when insurance is cancelled, when you move out of state, or you don't need the plates. It is also required to return the registration card: and to do this *before* cancelling the insurance. While the state say that you *may* be subject to a big fine for not doing this, the [actual requirement](http://www.mva.maryland.gov/vehicles/insurance/) pertains to driving uninsured, not being in possession of Maryland plates without insurance. They may then send the owner an insurance notification which has to be respond to, or the matter will go to collections and they will start to charge interest. If mail is being forwarded to you, you would get that notice (unless there is a "do not forward" instruction). Since the estate is presumably being probated in Maryland, the state of Maryland does have a way of collecting. The claims would be claims against the estate, and not you personally. As long as the car remains on your lot, one is not required to have Florida tags under [Florida law](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0300-0399/0316/Sections/0316.605.html).